# How to structure html code using VS code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

There is an HTML document in which there are no indents.

How to structure html code using VS code?
Using extensions or not using extensions.

**The initial state of the HTML document.**
[image]

**The required state of the HTML document.**
[image]

Comment: You can use this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter

Answer (score 1):

Right click in the file and select 'Format Document'. In Mac, the shortcut is 'Option + Shift + F'. VS Code has built in HTML CSS formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Install `Prettier` extension and just `Ctrl+Shift+I` to structure/decorate the  code

Answer (score 0):

You can press alt + shift + T or install Beautify extension, then press F1 and search beautfy, finally get your code indented.